# How to align this asp.net Button with other controls in the form using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, webforms

I am trying to update the style of my ASP.NET Web Forms solution by using the latest version of Bootstrap. I am currently struggling in aligning an ASP.NET Button control with the other controls in a horizontal form as shown in the following snapshot:
[image]

Here's the markup of the form:

```
    <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4">
            <div class="form-row mt-4">
                <div class="col-sm-5 pb-3">
                    <label>County</label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCounty" runat="server"
                        DataSourceID="odsCounty" AppendDataBoundItems="true"
                        DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Id" CssClass="form-control">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="">-- Select --</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsCounty" runat="server"
                        TypeName="CAS.Business.ContractorBL"
                        DataObjectTypeName="CAS.Data.Models.TCAS_Contractor"
                        SelectMethod="GetContractors"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4 pb-3">
                    <label>Request Number</label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtRequestNum" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"
                        CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-3 pb-3">
                    <label></label>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnFilter" runat="server" OnClick="lbtnFilter_Click"
                            CssClass="btn btn-primary"> 
                        <i class="fa fa-filter fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>Filter
                        </asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a couple things, perhaps in combination.
1. Try adding   to the empty label
2. Try removing the .form-group div container of the button.
3. Make your own css class to apply as a wrapper div for that button 
to space it properly. Something like this

```
.spacer {
  margin-top: 10px; // trial and error here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help in this regard.